# Unexpected results during custom number formatting and string replace when using certain currency symbols

Tags: c#, arabic, currency-formatting

I have a requirement to display all currencies in the following format:

```
"[Code] [Symbol]#,##0.00;[Code] [Symbol](#,##0.00)"
```

The user will chose a country and I get the currency code and symbol from an external service. I then use string.replace to set the currency code and symbol into the format string above.

So the value 123.456 (US Dollars) would be formatted as follows:

```
"USD $123.46"
```

This approach works for most currency symbols but I am having a problem with the currency symbol for Kuwait **د.ك**. I cannot seem to format any value to allow the symbol to appear before the numbers. I don't have the same problem with letters. I am thinking that this has to do with the fact that Arabic is written from right to left. The symbol even behaves that way in browser. I can't select it from left to right, selection starts from the right.
Also when I was testing in linqpad, my string was displayed as **[Kuwait_Symbol]#,##0.00**, however pasting in the stackoverflow textbox caused the string to be **د.ك#,##0.00**

Note that the ordering of the characters in the string has changed.

Though, I have a feeling that I will have to recommend that using symbols are not feasible, is there any way to get around this problem? Also, why can't the symbol be displayed before numbers?

Comment: How are you displaying this?  Is it in a console app?  A win form?  WPF?  Silverlight?  ASP.NET?

Comment: This is for an ASP.NET app. When debugging in VS though, I see that the value is formatted with the symbol at the end before it is displayed, so it doesn't matter what the platform is...Oddly enough VS's text visualizer displayed my number in the format and order that I expected i.e. with the symbol before the number, (although it displayed a placeholder not the actual symbol)

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from browsers and how they handle characters in right-to-left languages rather than the code that generates them. If you try

```
var kuwaitCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-KW");
Response.Write(Server.UrlEncode(amount.ToString("c", kuwaitCulture)));
```

you'll see that what gets returned clearly has the CurrencySymbol before the amount.

To get around this you can force left-to-right rendering in the browser with the corresponding Unicode character. For example,

```
Response.Write('\u202A' + kuwaitCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol + '\u202C' + amount);
```

renders correctly as per your specification.